# sql query : perform a where in if condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, rawsql

i've a situation like the following :

- i've a long query that join a table
- all the columns in joined tabled contain a column 'name'. in this table there are two names 'A' and 'B' (but can be C,D......Z, i don't know how many names we can have) and both of them have multiple rows, so i've n rows with name A and n rows with name B
- sometimes, based on the user input, i need to join the entire table (with all the names) BUT only put some condition where the name is 'A' (for example).

so :

joint table myTable (it will take all the results A,B,C...)
but if the name = 'A'
then A.priority = A.userInput
(for B,C... get them without additional conditions)

so, is there a solutions for this or i need to do multiple calls to the database ?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, if I understood this correctly, you're looking to conditionally join a table if one of the parameters has a certain value (`'A'`)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us a [mcve]. Please include a few sample rows from each table and sample results.

Comment: @El_Vanja need to get all the entire joined table but i need to apply conditions only to the rows ,in the joined table, that contain name 'A', and then get the others (B, C, ...) without extra condition conditions

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE name != 'A' OR A.priority = A.userInput`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `UNION ALL` clause for this

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.somecolumn = T2.somecolumn
  WHERE T2.name <> 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.somecolumn = T2.somecolumn
  WHERE T2.name = 'A' AND some condition
```

Comment: @MichalHynčica can you provide an example pls ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.somecolumn = T2.somecolumn WHERE T2.name != 'A' OR (some condition)` would give exactly same results as the query in this answer.